# Как запретить выделение текста в WebView?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Создал приложение, которое открывает содержимое html-файлов, изначально присутствующих в проекте, но не получается запретить возможность выделения текста, отображаемого в WebView. Как можно запретить выделять текст, ну и копировать его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user-select: none можете попробовать

Comment: а куда именно такой метод нужно прописать?

Comment: разобрался ' <style type="text/css">
   body { -webkit-user-select: none; }
   .enable { -webkit-user-select: text; }
  </style>'

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
webView.setLongClickable(false);
```

Comment: что-то не получилось применить, да и на сайте android не нашел документацию по OnLongClickListener для WebView

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. Это должно быть в `html`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body { -webkit-user-select: none; }
  .enable { -webkit-user-select: text; }
</style>
```